# MapReduce and Hive, Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

> For this problem, use the following data sets and approach:
>   Datasets: ~rose/public_html/590B/airline/200X.csv, where X is 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, or 8
>   Note: We are not including 2001.csv in our analysis since that data set is corrupted.
>
> You were probably wondering when the data would become big. Each of these files contains records for
>   several million flights. In total there are more than 53 million flights in this data set. If you are using wget to transfer the files, the command is of the form:
>   wget https://cse.sc.edu/~rose/590B/airline/2000.csv
>
> This problem is an organic extension of our understanding of map-reduce from counting words, to counting flights, to evaluating aviation volatility. Start by counting how many flights each airline has foreach of the annual datasets. For definition of the columns see: http://stat- computing.org/dataexpo/2009/the-data.html .
>
> The goal of this problem is identify those carriers that experience a major change in the number of flights from one year to the next. In the case of this problem we will define major change 1) a carrier may cease to exist and have no flights in subsequent years or 2) a new carrier may come into existence or 3) a carrier ceases to exist but in subsequent years is reincarnated with the same name.
>   Approach: find the number of flights per carrier for each of the annual dataset. Download the results for each year.

I am trying to figure this out but I keep getting stuck and have no idea how to even start. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a homework dump? Where exactly are you stuck and what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download each file using wget, as mentioned
2. Use hdfs -put command to upload all files to a single HDFS directory
3. Write code that parses the CSV columns and counts each airline (I assume you've written WordCount already)
4. Use that csv directory as your job input and run your code

It's not clear where Hive needs to fit into this, but I would assume you've been shown how to create an external table over text files, so you could do that and run something like `select count(*) from airlines group by airline`